# SQL - How to attach FileStream enabled db without log file

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, filestream

I'm trying to attach a FileStream enabled database without a log file. My SQL looks something like this:

```
USE master
CREATE DATABASE MyDB 
ON PRIMARY(NAME = N'MyDB', FILENAME = 'C:\myDB.MDF' ), 
FILEGROUP myFileGroup CONTAINS FILESTREAM ( NAME = myData, FILENAME = 'C:\myFileGroup')      
For Attach
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

> Msg 5173, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   One or more files do not match the primary file of the database.
>   If you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the correct files.
>   If this is an existing database, the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup.

Does anyone know if it's possible to attach a FileStream enabled database without the original log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog post:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/26/sql-server-attach-mdf-file-without-ldf-file-in-database/

I would personally go with this one:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDb ON
(FILENAME = N'C:\Database\Test\TestDb.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

And when you have your log rebuilt, you can enable filestream; or try to reattach with the filestream location.

Comment: I tried the 3 methods that were mentioned in your post.  All 3 of them will create a new log file, however, I still receive the same error: